# Pyqt5 how to run script every 5 minute or running script to check thread in web

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to make method run 5 minute or running script to check thread in web in pyqt5 ui with **while True** but the gui get frozen here the code, i google and found something like QRunnable or QPooThread, but still i can't understanding it.. how to implement it to Pyqt5 ui Designer

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # constructor using define first config
    def __init__(self):
        self.notify = webScrape() 
        self.errorFile = Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(
            __file__))+"\\resources\\log\\errors_log.txt")
        if os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(
                os.path.abspath(__file__))+"\\resources\\log") == False:
            os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(
                os.path.abspath(__file__))+"\\resources\\log")
        if not self.errorFile.exists() == True:
            open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) +
                 "\\resources\\log\\errors_log.txt", "w+")
        self.setPesanTime = None

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    # window
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(748, 542)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"\\resources\\img\\favicon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 450, 321, 16))
    self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
    self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
    self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 311, 16))
    self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
    self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.line.setObjectName("line")
    self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 10, 20, 441))
    self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
    self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
    # grid
    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 201, 101))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    # label
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 47, 13))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 161, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_2.setFont(font)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 161, 16))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_4.setFont(font)
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 30, 381, 16))
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 50, 381, 16))
    self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
    self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 70, 381, 16))
    self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
    self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 90, 381, 16))
    self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 30, 381, 16))
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 50, 381, 16))
    self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
    self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 70, 381, 16))
    self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
    self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 90, 381, 16))
    self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
    # checkbox
    self.chkSemuaKontak = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.chkSemuaKontak.setObjectName("chkSemuaKontak")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.chkSemuaKontak, 0, 0, 2, 1)
    self.chkSemuaGrup = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.chkSemuaGrup.setObjectName("chkSemuaGrup")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.chkSemuaGrup, 2, 0, 2, 1)
    self.chkAktifkanJawabPesan = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.chkAktifkanJawabPesan.setObjectName("chkAktifkanJawabPesan")
    self.chkAktifkanJawabPesan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 100, 381, 16))
    # textarea
    self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 281, 261))
    self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
    self.pesanTerima = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.pesanTerima.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 120, 381, 351))
    self.pesanTerima.setObjectName("pesanTerima")
    # button
    self.kirimBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.kirimBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 470, 91, 31))
    self.kirimBtn.setObjectName("kirimBtn")
    self.batalBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.batalBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 470, 91, 31))
    self.batalBtn.setObjectName("batalBtn")
    self.setAutoJawab = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.setAutoJawab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 480, 361, 31))
    self.setAutoJawab.setObjectName("setAutoJawab")
    # menu bar
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 748, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    # status bar
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    # declare event for properti
    self.kirimBtn.clicked.connect(self.kirimPesan)
    self.setAutoJawab.clicked.connect(self.setPesanClicked)
    self.chkSemuaKontak.toggled.connect(self.chkSemuaKontakChecked)
    self.chkSemuaGrup.toggled.connect(self.chkSemuaGrupChecked)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
```

the method / function that i want to run every 5 minute

```
def setPesanClicked(self):
    self.setPesanTime = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    while True:
        if self.notify.thereNewMessage() > 0:
            print('there something')
        else:
            print('wait 5 Minute')
            print(self.notify.thereNewMessage())
```

main run:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Function setPesanClicked should not contain an infinite loop - you just want to run it once every 5 minutes, not run it infinitely. Remove the While True loop.

Comment: yeah.. but how to check ***if self.notify.thereNewMessage() > 0:*** run without infinite loop in pyqt5 gui ?

Comment: If the function setPesanClicked is being called every 5 minutes (as you said), then you don't need the infinite loop. On the other hand, if you wish to keep the infiniite loop, and your function is running in its own thread, then use sleep(5*60) in the else part of the condition. sleep() suspends the currently running thread for the specified number of seconds.

Comment: i'm sorry, for not explain it properly... what i means it's how to run  setPesanClicked() in background without looping while true cause the gui will not responding..

Comment: Ok. Then you are asking about how to start a thread. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QThread to start your background task in a different thread and so avoid blocking your ui in the main thread. Python has its own threading module, but since you appear to be using PyQt it makes sense to use QThread instead.

Start by importing QThread:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
```

Declare your own QThread subclass, with the code in the run() method.

```
class bkgTask(QThread):

    def run(self):
        self.setPesanTime = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        while True:
            if self.notify.thereNewMessage() > 0:
                print('there something')
            else:
                print('wait 5 Minute')
                sleep(5*60)
                print(self.notify.thereNewMessage())
```

Create and run the background task:

```
bkgThread = bkgTask()
bkgThread.start()
```

Note that you start the task by calling start(), which in turn will call your run() method.

The first line goes with the imports. The last 2 lines start the thread, and should be somewhere in the main program - maybe between MainWindow.show ... and sys.exit, or in the MainWindow **init**. The bkgTask class needs to be declared somewhere with your other classes.

I'm not sure what the self in self.setPesanTime = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") refers to - you will probably need to move that line outside the bkgTask class unless you are going to use setPesanTime in the threaded code.

Comment: i try that got error QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running, but fixed it from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277345/python-error-qthread-is-undefined...
but anyway thank you, you're a hero

Comment: Glad it helped. From what you say it sounds like your thread object went out of scope and was garbage collected.